# organize data model objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, data-modeling

I have this visual part in my app. I've attached file below:

There are next user interface controls:

First UIScrollView (_blueScrollView) is located on main view of `UIViewController` that can contain many other views each one is called _magentaView...
Each _magentaView contains UIView (_labelView...) for storing UILabel objects. So there is some struct like `UITableView` in `UITableView`.

In my case all objects have `UIViewController` class.

I need to get access to all my labels that are storing in labelsViews. I need to get value of property text of those objects.

So if I make in standard case this will looks like this

```
for (UIViewController *magentaVC in scrollViewObjects) {
for (UIViewController *labelVC in magentaObjects) {
and get my UILabel objects here.
}
}
```

but as I think this is incorrect. Because I need to use data model for this instead to use UIViewController objects. What do you think about this and which way do I need to choose?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the job for a `UITableView`. The table itself has a scroll view embedded in it; magentaView 1 and 2 would be sections of the table, and the labelViews would be table view cells.

Comment: yes I know i have written about it. meant UITableView in UITableView